# What are Design-Time and Permission types?

Tags: c#, .net

I received the [CA1020:AvoidNamespacesWithFewTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182130.aspx) error, and within it I noticed this note:

> Design-time types and permissions should not be merged into other
>   namespaces to comply with this guideline. These types belong in their
>   own namespaces below your main namespace, and the namespaces should
>   end in **.Design** and **.Permissions**, respectively.

I'm not exactly sure what these are. I've never really heard of or have ever seen any library or framework that has a "Design" or "Permissions" namespace. What exactly are those and what would go in there?

Comment: I know one common assembly with the name **.Design**: `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Design`. Also most of the *DevExpress* assemblies have such pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Design-time types" - are types used in design time in Visual Studio (i.e. for property pages for custom controls/components). Check out [System.Windows.Forms.Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Design%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace with classes like [BorderSidesEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.bordersideseditor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

"Permissions" refer to CAS (code access security) permissions like [System.Security.**Permissions**.FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)